# Can I fade a background image into another background image in CSS (or even JS)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, linear-gradients

Everything I've seen for this basically uses a background image with a linear gradient over the top of it, and that won't work for me:

I have 2 divs with background images that appear next to each other vertically, with, say, 50px of overlap. **I would like to make the top 50px of the background image on the second div into a gradient so it fades in from transparent.**

Here's the setup to start:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: box-sizing:border-box;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  background-image: url('https://stevish.com/wpstevishcom/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/picture-0051-300x225.jpg');
}

.two {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-image: url('https://stevish.com/wpstevishcom/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/img_1530-large-225x300.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Unimportant content</div>
<div class="two">More unimportant content.</div>
```

And here's roughly what I want it to look like:

[image: The two backgrounds fading into each other]

I can't just upload a background image that fades one into the other because the content of the real divs is variable height, and the background needs to change only between the two divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mask can do it

```css
* {
  box-sizing: box-sizing:border-box;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  background-image: url('https://stevish.com/wpstevishcom/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/picture-0051-300x225.jpg');
}

.two {
  padding-top: 60px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  background-image: url('https://stevish.com/wpstevishcom/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/img_1530-large-225x300.jpg');
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#0000, #000 50px);
}
```

```html
<div class="one">Unimportant content</div>
<div class="two">More unimportant content.</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to stay a little more modular, you can only fade to a specific color (in my example white):

```css
div { height: 300px; width: 500px; background-size: cover; }

div:first-child {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/08/28/09/40/wild-7416210__340.jpg"); 
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent, white), url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/08/09/16/19/sea-7375377__340.jpg"); 
}
```

```html
<div>Test 1</div>
<div>Test 2</div>
```

Comment: If they wanted to stay more modular, they wouldn't use IDs. They certainly wouldn't use IDs with element selectors appended. Just the existing classes would be sufficient...

Comment: No, I know how to do that. I'm asking if there's a way to fade straight from one image to another.

Comment: @HereticMonkey You're right. I just typed it to show how an background-image with transparency is done - but I edited the answer to be more and more modular.